# Make [select2] a synonym of [jquery-select2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I just noticed there are two tags marked [select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select2) and [jquery-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-select2), which appear to be the same thing. The description on the info page for both tags is identical:

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

...save for a few extra pieces on the jquery-select2 tag. The jquery-select2 tag is more complete, and has far more subscribers. Since select2 is a jquery-based library, I'm unsure of the reason for having two separate tags. Does anyone know the reason for this?

A follow-up question would be, if there are no legitimate reasons for having the two, what is the solution?

**Edit**

Not certain whether I'm using 'burninate' correctly here, but updating question title to hopefully get this a little more attention, simply because I'd hate for the duplicate tag (if it is a duplicate) to continue to be used unnecessarily.

Comment: Perhaps make one of them a synonym?

Comment: It looks like all the [select2] tags have been migrated.  This is now complete.

Comment: Hmm, I probably should have double checked before bumping the question. Thanks @JasonMArcher for the note.

Comment: [select2] is back again. It should be synonymed this time to prevent further creation.

Comment: @miken32 they've been syn'd now.

Comment: Select2 is back with 800+ questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @JasonMArcher, it appears the old [select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select2) tag is now gone.

Comment: There are 800+ select2 questions and thousands of jquery-select2 ones. Should one not be merged into another? Or is one a synonym? For example I cannot use [select2] in the search form, it is autoreplaced by [jquery-select2]

Additionally there are two version specific ones jquery-select2-3 and -4